# Can a transmuter make silver for his cleric buddy to make holy water?

Tags: dnd-5e, spell-components

A transmuter can use his minor alchemy feature to transmute stone or wood into silver (other stuff too, but that is irrelevant).

> Starting at 2nd level when you select this school, you can temporarily alter the physical properties of one nonmagical object, changing it from one substance into another. You perform a special alchemical procedure on one object composed entirely of wood, stone (but not a gemstone), iron, copper, or silver, transforming it into a different one of those materials. For each 10 minutes you spend performing the procedure, you can transform up to 1 cubic foot of material. After 1 hour, or until you lose your concentration (as if you were concentrating on a spell), the material reverts to its original substance.

A cleric can use silver dust to create holy water.

Is the silver from transmutation useable as ritual component?

Items conjured cannot be used as expensive material components, but i am not sure if this rule also applies to this wizard class feature.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a hard RAW answer to this so it is left to the DM's discretion to extrapolate from similar abilities.

Obvious answer to me is "No" although this is a transmutation and therefore actually does constitute the material actually being silver for the duration it indicates in the creation of Holy Water that it requires Silver *Dust*. A DM can therefore rule that each speck of dust is an individual object (which they technically are) and thus only one speck can be transmuted.

A DM is free to rule that scraping flecks off a transmuted object also revert to their previous makeup as those pieces are no longer subject to the power being a separate object.

Your DM's mileage may vary but this is tricky and can be a source of abuse albeit this assumes being able to find a buyer for the Holy Water at face value and procuring materials that would provide enough dust to create it. And of course time away from adventuring.

It would obviously be more abusive to be duping a merchant or money changer into purchasing the silver outright. Since one cubic foot of silver is 654.91 pounds which at 5gp per pound is 3274.55 gold piece in trade. It would be likely be widely known about magic and there would be tests or holding periods before payment would be rendered to the wizard as well. This of course is a bit outside the scope of the question but was worth mentioning as an argument on ways to abuse the ability.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can make holy water with it.

Then, when the silver reverts to whatever it was before, your holy water becomes contaminated water.

Comment: It takes 1 hour to create Holy Water normally, so if the ingredients are required for the whole ritual from the start, the holy water would start spoiled (but I guess 1 L1 spell slot for 1 hours temp holy water seems fair). Other uses for X gp of silver dust - e.g. Magic Circle - would also be allowed by this ruling, so perhaps worth expanding this answer to show how the interpretation can work. I kind of like it, in that it makes the ability useful and fits with the theme of it (other 2nd level Wizard powers can be very effective, so saving some money on a few specific spells seems OK)

Comment: @NeilSlater The ability is extremely useful even without this...